# How to set the position of user control

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I set сontrol's alignmentes to stretch, but

```
var Parent = new PivotItem():
var msg = new myControl();
Parent.Content = msg; // located in a strange way, the control is clipped
```

Comment: Show us XAML of your myControl and xaml where Pivot is located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the parent width and height are larger or the same as the msg Control's width and height